# Issue with container div not resizing as the page size changes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on an issue in which my container element is not resizing as the page changes size, which would lead to issues displaying the page on smaller screens (e.g. content is hidden, and the user cannot scroll down far enough to see it). I gave the offending container (section.padder-content.scrollable) a smaller than usual height, so it is easier to see. Here is an image demonstrating the issue:

[The issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HAky.png)

On the left is the screen before resizing, and on the right is after resizing-- here, the user can no longer see the "Create" button, and cannot scroll down any further to see it. I wanted to try and post images of the source code of the three elements I think are contributing to the issue, but I don't have enough reputation at the moment. But basically the offending container has:

```
position: absolute;
height: 600px;
overflow-y: auto;
```

Its parent has:

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: top;
float: none;
position: relative;
border-spacing: 0;
```

And the parent's parent:

```
height: 100%;
overflow-y: auto;
min-height: 90%;
max-height: 90%;
margin-bottom: 10px;
display: table;
table-layout: fixed;
border-spacing: 0;
width: 100%;
```

I tried experimenting with the positioning of the table-cells, changing the display to literally everything else, and nothing can quite get it to work. I am thinking it might have something to do with the mix of pixel heights and percentages, but when I experiment with those, I seem to make it worse. This isn't my code, and there are three separate css files being used: site.css, bootstrap.css, and app.css ([Scale from ThemeForest](http://themeforest.net/item/scale-web-application-admin-template/7016215)). There's a lot of interaction potentially going on here that I don't quite understand, so any help would be appreciated. As a side-note: I am using IE11 at the moment, because although I found a hacky fix for Chrome/FF, it completely ruins the display in IE.

Please let me know if there are any more details I should provide.

Comment: Could you post all your HTML and CSS, it will help figuring out what the problem is

Comment: @IndieRok : Here are more images and their source code/css styles:

The offending container: http://i.imgur.com/ze4yimO.png / Source:  http://i.imgur.com/qnrZcpT.png

Its parent element: http://i.imgur.com/xsre8Y8.png / Source : http://i.imgur.com/Br6NyY2.png

And parent's parent: http://i.imgur.com/2N6f6k8.png / Source: http://i.imgur.com/04nA7r2.png

Comment: post your code on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed the issue. There were a couple of competing issues. The critical issue was that the template I used (Scale from ThemeForest) had javascript code (app.js) that didn't quite work properly in IE11. The offending code:

```
// fix vbox
var fixVbox = function(){
  $('.ie11 .vbox').each(function(){
    $(this).height($(this).parent().height());
  });
  return true;
}
fixVbox();
```

The 'vbox' would resize correctly if you *increased* the window size, but not if you ***decreased*** the window size, which is often what I was doing when trying to see how the site would work on mobile. There were elements that got their heights calculated based on their parents, and those parent elements calculated their heights from their child elements... so when the window size was decreased, and the *fixVbox()* function did not correctly calculate the new height, it caused issues with all of the elements.

In all, a very specific and difficult bug to track down-- a problem with the template itself that I was using.

My solution (for anyone else using this same template):

**In app.js:**

```
// unmobile
$window.width() < 768 && mobile();
// resize
var $resize;
$window.resize(function() {
  clearTimeout($resize);
  $resize = setTimeout(function(){
    setHeight();
    $window.width() < 767 && mobile();
    $window.width() >= 768 && mobile('reset') && fixVbox();
  }, 500);
});
```

to:

```
    $window.width() >= 768 && mobile('reset'); // && fixVbox();
```

and:

```
// fix vbox
var fixVbox = function(){
  $('.ie11 .vbox').each(function(){
    $(this).height($(this).parent().height());
  });
  return true;
}
fixVbox();
```

to:

```
//fixVbox();
```

Once the parent/child elements started resizing correctly, it was just a matter of fixing my css to account for the changes (e.g. I had to push my container window down 103px because that was the height of my navbar at the top, etc.)